# Order users by number of posts (includes custom post type)

Tags: custom-post-types, users

I am using the function below to count posts for users (including custom post types). I am putting together a list of users and want to order them by this count function. The orderby options for the get_users() function are limited, and post_count doesn't include custom post types. How can I order my users using this function?

Function:

```
function foo_count_posts( $userid, $post_type = '', $post_status = 'publish') {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = $userid AND (post_type = 'post' OR post_type='foo') AND post_status = '$post_status'"; 
    $counter = $wpdb->get_var($query); 

    return apply_filters( 'get_usernumposts', $counter, $userid );  
}
```

Then I call the function to get the count:

```
echo foo_count_posts($user_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the above function works well for you to get the count for the posts including the `custom post types` and you just need help in ordering the users using this count.

I assume you already have the list of user ids lets say the array `$userids`

Lets use **[asort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)** and **[arsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)** to do so

Put the above code in the active theme's **`functions.php`** file and use the below in the file where you need to get the ordering

```
$arr = array();
foreach( $userids as $userid ) {
    $arr[$userid] = foo_count_posts($userid);
}
```

Now **`$arr`** is the array with userid as key and post count as the value

To get the ascending order use

```
asort($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

To get the descending order use

```
arsort($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```